# How do I lookup the correct time-zone with tzlocal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytz

I'm running Debian and my current time-zone is set to *America/New_York* in `/etc/timezone`, and my `/etc/localtime` is properly set (it has the same checksum as `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York`). I'm trying to lookup the time-zone programmatically using `tzlocal` which uses `pytz` internally. I'm getting a weird result though.

```
>>> import tzlocal
>>> tzlocal.get_localzone()
<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>
```

I should be receiving EDT with a -04:00 offset (expressed as a *timedelta*), not whatever LMT is with a -04:56 offset. I would expect to receive:

```
<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>
```

Why is the offset wrong?

Comment: @wim Thank you, my searching was failing me.